# jQuery .hide() im doing something wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can't seem to get the .hide() function of jQuery working.

Code

```
<img class="jh-search" src="http://www.placehold.it/100x100" />
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('.jh-search').click(function(){
        (this).hide();
    });
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dneo7yez/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$(this)` is the current context jQuery object

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('.jh-search').click(function(){
        $(this).hide();     //$ to wrap as jQuery object.
    });
});
```